# Combinatorics - all the ways to paint 30 balls.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

You have 30 white balls, each ball can be painted in red or yellow,
yellow balls can be painted with a purple stripe but can also stay completely yellow.

In how many ways can we paint the balls if no ball should stay white, and there should be exactly 5 red balls.

What I did is this:

First we need to pick 5 balls to paint in red, all the ways to choose them is:
${30 \choose 5}$

We've left with 25 balls that have to be yellow, I counted all the possible ways by counting all the subsets in this set, hence: $2^{25}$

So in total the answer is: ${30 \choose 5} \cdot 2^{25}$

I'm not sure about my answer, is it correct? is there any better way of solving this?
I'd be glad for some help.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, if you consider balls of the same color as identical, then $25$ balls can be painted in either one of $2$ options, hence the answer is $2^{25}$.

Comment: So, is my answer correct?

Comment: Well, if you consider balls of the same color as identical, then no, since $2^{25}\neq\binom{30}{5}\cdot2^{25}$.

Comment: @barakmanos if the balls are only distinguishable on base of the way they are colored then there are not $2^{25}$ but $26$ solutions. $k$ yellow balls with purple stripe for $k=0,1,2,\dots,25$ and $25-k$ yellow balls without a purple stripe.

Comment: @drhab: Good catch!!! I'd call it an answer (but perhaps should refer to the case where the balls **are distinguishable** (by their "original ID" or something like that).

Comment: @FigureItOut: are the white balls numbered or distinguished in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the balls are distinguishable on something else than their colors (e.g. they have a number) then your answer is correct.

If the balls are only distinguishable on the way they are colored then $26$ possibilities arise. The options are: $k$ yellow balls with a purple stripe and $25-k$ yellow balls without a purple stripe with $k$ ranging over $\{0,1,2,\dots,25\}$.